# Remove unlock option from gnome control center

Tags: gnome

I want to remove that unlock button from the top so a normal users allowed to add a printer from gnome control center. I have added the user to the lp group and it works from the cups web administration page. How can  enable any user to access that setting ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Late reply but I ran into this requirement today and this post is high in the Google results.

In short, you need to apply a local policykit ... policy, that allows the users you want. The file should be created in `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` named something like `50-printer-open-access.pkla` *(note, this is the location for policies in debian/ubuntu systems - others I don't know)*

**Note: please see comments below regarding potential file syntax changes on modern distros, I can confirm the examples below are working on ubuntu 18.04**

Example 1, allows literally anyone:

```
[Printer administration]
Identity=*
Action=org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Example 2, allows any users in the `lpadmin` group:

```
[Printer administration]
Identity=unix-group:lpadmin
Action=org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

A reference I found handy:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/708261/how-do-i-set-the-policy-for-users-to-modify-the-network-state-and-connections

Comment: @don_crissti thanks for the heads up - it appears that ubuntu 18.04 may be using both policykit and polkit then? The ubuntu policykit overrides are still using the ini -style syntax

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks again for the heads up -

Answer (score 2):

The first answer didn't work for me on Fedora and so I found [this document](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Printing/ConfigurationTool).

Adding this to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/90-printer-admin.rules` worked immediately, didn't even have to close and reopen the control panel.

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (/^org\.opensuse\.cupspkhelper\.mechanism\./.test(action.id) &&
        subject.isInGroup("lp")) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

In Fedora the admin group is `lp`, not `lpadmin`, so adjust as needed.